# How to imitate zune panning control

Tags: wpf

I'm looking to imitate the following control, found in the zune software, in the quickplay tab. When you move the mouse from left to right the boxes new, pinned and history move to the opposite direction.

I'm thinking of applying a method to the mousemove handler which checks for the relative position of the cursor and then moves a grid containing panels accordingly but before I try to reinvent the wheel I'd like to ask around if there are people who have more experience with this, especially getting a fluid motion.

Please let me know

Comment: or maybe this one http://sachabarber.net/?p=628

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this http://sachabarber.net/?p=829